# Override the "It works" page from Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I change the output of just the domain name (including the trailing slash (`/`), of course)? I'd really like the URL to end at the domain name rather than having an ugly index.html there.

To further explain: Apache is returning the page just fine when the WWW-qualified URL is used (e.g. `www.example.com`), but when just domainname.tld (`example.com`) is used, it just gives the "It Works!" message.

Comment: What OS or Distro are you on? Is it an install from source or from a package?

Comment: running a fresh amazon ec2 ubuntu ami, Apache 2.2.17.   I installed with zero options (even left PREFIX at default).  It sounds like others have been helped by the advice others have given, but in my case: I can't find a welcome.conf (sudo find fails me!), OR an /etc/apache2 directory.

Answer (score 3):

Either add an index file in the document root, or rename `welcome.conf` in the configuration directory to something that the configuration files won't pick up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control this from the config file

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default